# Add a row DataTable with json

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatables

I have a table with DataTable, JQuery, and I return a json with php, but not add data in row of table.

```
var table = $('#list').DataTable();
table.row.add([{"id":"1","name":"other", "action":"edit"}]);
```

Comment: **1**) You can only use `table.row.add()` with an object literal *if* you have created the table with a `columns` or `columnDefs` section which define `data` indexes **2**) When you insert a new row with `table.row.add()` you *must* include *all* `data` indexes declared in the above mentioned `columns` or `columnDefs` sections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line should be work:

```
table.row.add(['Fiona White', 32, 'Edinburgh']).draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var table = $('#list').DataTable();
table.row.add([{"id":"1","name":"other", "action":"edit"}]).draw();
```

Comment: please correct your spelling tabla.row.add to table.row.add

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var table = $('#list').DataTable();
table.row.add({"id":"1","name":"other", "action":"edit"}).draw();
```